# Prove that $\left|G\right|\,|\,n!$

Tags: group-theory

**Question**

Let G a simple group, X finite group such that $|X|=n$, and let suppose that $G\curvearrowright X$  isn't trivial action.

Prove that $G$  is finite and prove that $\left|G\right|\,|\,n!$

**My attempt**

If $|G|=\infty$ then $\frac{1}{\left|X\right|}\cdot\sum_{G.x\in_{G}\setminus^{X}}\frac{1}{\left|Stab_{G}\left(x\right)\right|}=\frac{1}{\left|G\right|}\rightarrow0$ and that's impossible.

I dont how to prove that $\left|G\right|\,|\,n!$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to show that if $G$ acts non-trivially on $X$, then $G$ is a subgroup of $S_{|X|}$...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ is simple and acts on a finite set $X$ with a non-trivial action.
Let $\rho : G \to \mathfrak{S}(X)$ be the action. $\ker \rho \leqslant G$ is a normal subgroup of $\rho$. As the action is non-trivial, $\ker \rho \neq G$. As $G$ is simple, then $\ker \rho = \{1\}$. Thus, $\rho$ is an injection.  Remark finally that $|\mathfrak{S}(X)| = |X|!$ if $|X|<\infty$. Then $G$ is finite, as a subgroup of the finite group $\mathfrak{S}(X)$, and by Lagrange's theorem, $|G|$ divides $ |\mathfrak{S}(X)|$.

Answer (score 0):

The action $G\curvearrowright X$ induces a group homomorphism $\phi: G \to S_X$, where $S_X$ is the group of all permutations of a set $X$. Since the action is non-trivial, $\ker \phi \neq G$. Thus $\ker \phi = \{1\}$ by the simplicity of $G$. Now the first isomorphism theroem yields $G \cong G / \ker \phi \cong \text{im} (\phi) \leq S_X $. Apply the Lagrange's theorem.